# What does the lettering on my shirt mean? (Characters identified: 花樣年華)

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

[image]

My friend gave me this shirt, I've been trying to figure out what it means. Can anyone translate it?

Comment: See also https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/8092-%E8%8A%B1%E6%A0%B7%E5%B9%B4%E5%8D%8E/

Answer (score 3):

That shirt might be the souvenir for the movie "花样年华".  Its English name is "**In the Mood for Love**", according to [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%8A%B1%E6%A0%B7%E5%B9%B4%E5%8D%8E/35761?fr=aladdin).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your friend is telling you to get out there and enjoy the prime of your life! Or they had a T-shirt with some weird symbols that they wanted to get rid of.

The characters are: 花样年华 / 花樣年華

The meaning is **The prime of one's life**.

In this phrase, I would take **花样** to mean happy and prosperous, and **年华** to mean time or a time period.

Below is the Pleco entry for this phrase:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am chinese, i think it means that the best wish your friend giving you.  He thinks you are in the best of your time like beautiful flower.